# Why is my plotly figure drawing a wrong line?

Tags: plotly, ternary, plotly.graph-objects

I am making a ternary plot in plotly a needed to use graph_objects because express didn't support certain things I needed to do. While I was drawing a line on my plot. Plotly ignores one of the points I give and draws a different line. Does anybody knows why and how I can fix this?
Here is the minimal code example.
Tie_line behaves as expected to show how it should work and Tie_line2 makes the wrong line.

The image shows figure I got with wrong data point.

[image]

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

Tie_line = go.Scatterternary(a=[0.18716, 0.45514, None],
                             b=[0.76559, 0.0415, None],
                             c=[0.04725, 0.50336, None], mode='lines',
                             line_width=2, line_color='#0000ee', text='Tie-line 1', name="Eerste tie_line")

Tie_line2 = go.Scatterternary(a=[0.03773, 0.23891, None],
                             b=[0.95075, 0.0935, None],
                             c=[0.01152, 0.75174, None], mode='lines',
                             line_width=2, line_color='#ff0000', text='Tie-line', name="Tweede tie_line")

fig = go.Figure(data=[Tie_line2, Tie_line])
fig.update_ternaries(aaxis_title_text='Isopropanol', baxis_title_text='Cyclohexaan', caxis_title_text='Water')
fig.update_layout(title_text='Ternair diagram', title_x=0.465)
fig.show()
```

Comment: As I have answered some of your questions in my past, I am not good at this type of graph. Here is the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585586/ternary-plot-from-plotly) of my past answers. The coordinates are the start and end points of the left side (a) of the triangle, the start and end points of the base (b) of the triangle, and the start and end points of the right side (c) of the triangle. See also an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639653/how-to-plot-a-ternary-chart-with-lines-using-plotly-python) of drawing an additional triangle in the graph.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the problem isn't that I don't know how to draw a line on the figure. The problem is that for some reason I don't understands python ignores the end point of the second line I am drawing. Instead it thinks that a=0.22, b=0.86, c=0.69 is the point I want. Do you know what part of the plotly code could cause this?

Comment: I found what the problem was one 0 is missing before the nine the sum is greater than 1 and python is trying to compensate to make it one. In case somone makes the same mistake as me.

Comment: Each must be a[0]+b[0]+c[0]=1,a[1]+b[1]+c[1]=1 respectively.